# How-to lookup cell address

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying to do a lookup, and want to get the address of the result.
Let's say A5->A20 contain names and I want to match it with the name in B1.

=cell("address",LOOKUP(B1,A20:A21))

This gives me a N/A.
What should I do to get the address as a result?

Comment: Is the address the final result or are you going to use it in another formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the Address:

```
="A" & MATCH(B1,A:A,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(B1,$A1:$A20,0), 1),"")
```

NB: `1` hard codes column `A`.